# How can I replace Claimsprincipal for aws cognito Oauth2 in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

Im trying out Aws Cognito in my asp.net core MVC-solution.

I register Cookie-auth in my startup and add a listener to the OnCreatingTicket-event to parse JWT-token I get upon successful login like below:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Cognito";
        })
           .AddCookie()
           .AddOAuth("Cognito", options =>
           {
               options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
               options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:Secret"];
               options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/sign-in");
               options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://xx.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize";
               options.TokenEndpoint = "https://xx.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token";
               options.SaveTokens = true;
               options.ClaimsIssuer = "https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxx";

               options.Events = new OAuthEvents
               {
                    OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicket
               };
           });
```

However I have only been able to find the Principal.AddIdentity-method which lets me add the new CLaimsIdentity, but what I want is to replace the current Identity as this is needed for asp.net core's AntiForgery-system.

Parsing jwt-token:

```
    private static Task OnCreatingTicket(OAuthCreatingTicketContext context)
    {
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var idToken = context.TokenResponse.Response["id_token"];
        var jwtToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(idToken.ToString());

        var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims);

//how to override context.Principal?
        context.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Any ideas how to override the current context.Principal.Identity instead of adding a new one?

Answer (score 0):

The `Principal` property on the context is mutable so replace it with a new one.

```
context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(appIdentity);
```